# Hide error message with custom message or reactive button in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

When I run the app, I get an error on the default screen. I'm not concerned about the error as the app works. When I select inputs the app works well.

What I would like to do is to hide the error on the default screen. This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error: <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: admit  ~  
   ^
```

I don't want to add a button to solve this issue as I would like to keep the app reactive. But if there is a way to add a button and still keep it reactive, I'd love that idea.

I'm also open to the idea of having a custom message on the default screen like "Select Dependent and Independent Variables" or something like that.

```
library(shiny)

mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("input1", "Dependent Variable", choices = names(mydata)), 
            selectInput("input2", "Independent Variable(s)", choices = names(mydata), multiple = TRUE)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("output2"),
           verbatimTextOutput("output1")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    left_vars <- reactive({input$input1})
    
    right_vars <- reactive({
        rights = input$input2
        rights <- paste(rights, collapse=" + ")
        })
   
    log_formula <- reactive({as.formula(paste(left_vars(), " ~ ", right_vars()))})
    
    output$output1 <- renderPrint({summary(glm(formula = log_formula(), data = mydata, family = "binomial"))})
    
    output$output2 <- renderPrint({
        paste(paste0(left_vars(), " ~", right_vars()))
    })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using a `validate` function for the custom message https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a validation to the reactive term lets you write custom error messages with conditional statements.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("input1", "Dependent Variable", choices = names(mydata)), 
      selectInput("input2", "Independent Variable(s)", choices = names(mydata), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("output2"),
      verbatimTextOutput("output1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  left_vars <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$input1, "Please enter a dependant variable"))

      input$input1})
  
  right_vars <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$input2, "Please enter an independant variable"))
      
    rights = input$input2
    rights <- paste(rights, collapse=" + ")
  })
  
  log_formula <- reactive({as.formula(paste(left_vars(), " ~ ", right_vars()))})
  
  output$output1 <- renderPrint({summary(glm(formula = log_formula(), data = mydata, family = "binomial"))})
  
  output$output2 <- renderPrint({
    paste(paste0(left_vars(), " ~ ", right_vars()))
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**: In case you are wondering why it is displaying the same warning twice. It is because you have two render functions that can not be completed until an independent variable is selected.